# Should we create new tables instead of filtering 1 large table?

Tags: performance, query-performance

In an application with `group`s and `post`s where each `post` can be in exactly 1 `group`, we can have the table `POSTS(post_id, group_id, post_content)`. However, there's gonna be a lot of posts in a lot of groups and filtering for posts in 1 or more groups can take a lot of resources. Instead, I think we can just create a new table `$(GROUP_ID)_POSTS(post_id, post_content)` where `$GROUP_ID` is the `group_id` from the `POSTS` table. I don't know  about the specifics but I think joining several tables is gonna be a lot faster than filtering through a lot of `group_id`s.

Is this a good way to improve performance? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

The "Table-per-*whatever*" Model *almost always* breaks down eventually.
It's usually when some "Administrative" function needs to go across the 20,000 tables you've built up in one query, but the DBMS limits you to just **61** tables in any one query (MySQL).

Any half-decent DBMS with sensibly-indexed Tables will cope with your first structure (post_id, group_id, post_content) *with ease*.